# OpenStack Nova fails to connect to libvirt (not socket issue!)

Tags: openstack, libvirt, kolla-ansible, nova

We're trying to deploy OpenStack on hardened Debian-based Linux distro via Kolla-ansible and we seem to be almost done but facing the issue with the nova_compute container which complaints:

```
2021-09-12 08:56:34.365 7 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] Connection event '0' reason. 
 'Failed to connect to libvirt: Unable to query peer security context: No data available
```

and restarts permanently.

Here are relevant config snippets:

```
(venv) root@server11:~# grep nova /etc/kolla/globals.yml 
nova_backend_ceph                  : "yes"
nova_compute_virt_type             : "qemu"
(venv) root@server11:~# cat /etc/kolla/config/nova/nova-compute.conf 
[libvirt]
virt_type=qemu
cpu_mode = none
(venv) root@server11:~#
```

Tried to figure out the root cause myself, read the docs, googled but to no avail, so any suggestions on how to fix the issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the getpeercon() method failed. This method is only run it libvirt is built with SELinux support.  The "No data available" return value suggests perhaps SELinux is turned off, but that should already have been caught by the "ENOSYS" / "NOPROTOOPT" checks.

Comment: Thanks, DanielB!

Neither host distro (Astra Linux, hardened Debian 9 derivative) nor containers' base image (Ubuntu) have nothing to do with SELinux.

Bearing in this in mind, did I understand correctly according to your answer the way to work around the issue is to customize Kolla-ansible in nova_libvirt part to use libvirt built without SELinux support?

Comment: Astra Linux has replaced SELinux with its own unique mandatory access control system. That may be why libvirt has gotten confused? In any case, a build of libvirt and its related packages without SELinux support seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

@alex-vrublevskiy As I can see you tried to deploy it with Kolla. Have you solved the issue with Astra? What was the OS inside the docker kolla-libvirt container?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573820)